# Can not use command telnet in git bash

Tags: telnet, git-bash

I try to use the command `telnet` in Git Bash, but it shows this error:

> bash:telnet: command not found

My operating system is Windows 10. Any idea is appreciated.

Comment: `telnet` is poorly scriptable anyway; perhaps you want `netcat`

Answer (score 31, accepted):

That's because telnet is not provided with git.

In windows, you need to go to control panel, programs, turn windows features on/off and enable the telnet client.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I turn on the service successfully.But when I run it, I got no response from the server. I mean,  nothing appears in the command line. Could you help me with that?

Comment: what server you trying to connect to?

Comment: after enable telnet service, a new windows command line allows telnet but gitbash does not do anything, no error either.

Comment: I got response with cmd(Run as administrator) when exec `telnet localhost 2181` ~ black screen appears: write `srvr`

Answer (score 8):

#### Enable telnet

Control Panel > Programs > Turn Windows features on or off > *Check* Telnet Client > Ok

#### Invoke telnet on git bash

`telnet` utility need to be invoked with `winpty` to work on `git bash`.

Example:

```
 MINGW64 ~
$ which telnet
/c/WINDOWS/system32/telnet
```

```
 MINGW64 ~
$ winpty telnet localhost 2181
    Zookeeper version: 3.4.14-4c25d480e66aadd371de8bd2fd8da255ac140bcf, built on 03/06/2019 16:18 GMT
```

Comment: In WIndows 10, `winpty telnet localhost 2181` is giving an error ""winpty: error: cannot start 'telnet': Not found in PATH""

Comment: @abdulrashid, you need to enable the telnet client

Answer (score 3):

For a programmatic solution, you can use Deployment Image Servicing and Management (DISM)

In windows command prompt, you can use [`dism` to enable features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/enable-or-disable-windows-features-using-dism#to-enable-windows-features) like this:

```sh
C:\> dism /online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:TelnetClient
```

Or in Powershell, with the [`DISM` Module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/dism/?view=win10-ps) use [`Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/dism/enable-windowsoptionalfeature?view=win10-ps) like this:

```
PS> Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature FeatureName:TelnetClient
```