# How can I get telnet to work successfully in Gitbash?

Tags: windows, telnet, tcpclient, git-bash

I am trying to run telnet in gitbash on windows, but when I enter the command `telnet`, I just get returned to my command line. I already enabled the telnet client like the link at the bottom of this question explained.

The problem now is that when I type telnet into gitbash, nothing happens, and I am just returned a new command line. If I open up a windows shell and type telnet then it runs as expected, which leads me to believe it's an issue with gitbash.

How can I get telnet to work successfully in Gitbash?

Link to a similar question, but only explains how to enable the tcp client, not how to get gitbash to run it: [Can not use command telnet in git bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38155583/can-not-use-command-telnet-in-git-bash#38155624)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can not use command telnet in git bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38155583/can-not-use-command-telnet-in-git-bash)

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that git-bash is meant to run such programs. It may be possible to do so, but it only contains minimal utilies, often useful to manage your repositories.

If you want extended unix-system on windows, use a [VM](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_virtuelle) or Windows Subsystem for Linux ([often called bash on windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux)).

If you just want to run the windows telnet program from git bash, you can simply write the path to it, eg `C:/Users/Documents/telnet/telnet.exe`

Comment: Thank you, I started to come to that conclusion too. I usually dual-boot into Ubuntu, but was hoping that I could use Git Bash in this case. I decided to just install Ubuntu for Windows and enable the Windows Subsystem for Linux feature.I used GitBash as a workaround, but I think I will just switch to this solution since it seems to fix all my others issues as well.

Comment: Thanks, @NanoPish. There are a couple solutions, but I now use WSL for anything that doesn't work any more haha.

Answer (score 1):

Just to complement @NanoPish's answer, telnet need to be invoked with winpty*(for those who used MinTTY as terminal emulator)* on git bash to work.

Example:

```
 MINGW64 ~
$ which telnet
/c/WINDOWS/system32/telnet
```

```
 MINGW64 ~
$ winpty telnet localhost 2181
    Zookeeper version: 3.4.14-4c25d480e66aadd371de8bd2fd8da255ac140bcf, built on 03/06/2019 16:18 GMT
```